# Why cant I use Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding.Windows.Render?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, qr-code

I'm using [QrCode.Net](http://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http://qrcodenet.codeplex.com/&ei=WZxWUIzPGIKc9gTitoGIBg&usg=AFQjCNHE5N5PFWEkh6pzhgzaf3y1Uq3wPQ&sig2=WfrI-6xsVdR1huZDE-GFJg) library version 0.3 and I need to use `Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding.Windows.Render` in order to create images with qrcode [ISizeCalculation](http://qrcodenet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Size&referringTitle=Renderer) but I'm missing somethig or there's another version outhere. What can be the problem?
Anyway I found a solution for people with the same problem and they wanna create images with the same fixed size. Here is the code:

```
private void gen_qr_file(string file_name, string content, int image_size)
{
    string new_file_name = file_name;

    QrEncoder qrEncoder = new QrEncoder(ErrorCorrectionLevel.H);
    QrCode qrCode = new QrCode();
    qrEncoder.TryEncode(content, out qrCode);

    Renderer renderer = new Renderer(image_size, Brushes.Black, Brushes.White);

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    renderer.WriteToStream(qrCode.Matrix, ms, ImageFormat.Png);

    var image = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(ms), new Size(new Point(200, 200)));

    image.Save(new_file_name + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);

}
```

This generate a png image of 200x200 pixels with the qrcode.

The library itself has a method to do this, but I need to include the RENDER thing and I can't. Someone knows what's the problem?

Answer (score 4):

```
private void gen_qr_file(string file_name, string content, int image_size) {

    string new_file_name = file_name;

    QrEncoder qrEncoder = new QrEncoder(ErrorCorrectionLevel.H);
    QrCode qrCode = new QrCode();
    qrEncoder.TryEncode(content, out qrCode);

    Renderer renderer = new Renderer(image_size, Brushes.Black, Brushes.White);

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    renderer.WriteToStream(qrCode.Matrix, ms, ImageFormat.Png);

    var imageTemp = new Bitmap(ms);

    var image = new Bitmap(imageTemp, new Size(new Point(image_size, image_size)));

    image.Save(new_file_name + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);

}
```

Note: Only 2 lines are modified. I hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 3):

Use `FixedCodeSize`.  See example below which will produce a 400x400px image, with each 'module' (block) getting smaller the more data is added.

```
var qrEncoder = new QrEncoder(ErrorCorrectionLevel.M);
var qrCode = qrEncoder.Encode("my value");

var renderer = new GraphicsRenderer(new FixedCodeSize(400, QuietZoneModules.Zero), Brushes.Black, Brushes.White);
renderer.WriteToStream(qrCode.Matrix, ImageFormat.Png, /* OUTPUT STREAM */);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to include both of the following statements:

using Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding;
using Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding.Windows.Controls;

Also, how big is Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding.dll ?

It should be over 80K or you have the wrong one.

I had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation Only change `GraphicsRenderer`

```
private string gen_qr_file(string file_name, string content, int image_size)
{
    string new_file_name = file_name;
    QrEncoder qrEncoder = new QrEncoder(ErrorCorrectionLevel.H);
    QrCode qrCode = new QrCode();
    qrEncoder.TryEncode(content, out qrCode);

    GraphicsRenderer renderer = new GraphicsRenderer(
        new FixedCodeSize(400, QuietZoneModules.Zero), 
        Brushes.Black, 
        Brushes.White);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    renderer.WriteToStream(qrCode.Matrix, ImageFormat.Png, ms);
    var imageTemp = new Bitmap(ms);
    var image = new Bitmap(imageTemp, new Size(new Point(200, 200)));
    image.Save(new_file_name, ImageFormat.Png);

    return new_file_name;
}
```